# Any recommendations for a lightweight framework with MS SQL Server support

Tags: sql-server-2005, php

Note: I have been out of touch with the PHP world for quite a long time. I am primarily a Python developer.

I have to build a small app in PHP5. Please suggest me a lightweight framework which:

- Has MS SQL Server Support that runs on Linux as the  app will be running on Ubuntu.
- Is fast to learn, use and setup.

Performance is not a critical issue. As the app will be used on a private LAN by about 10 people for data entry mainly.

**Suggestion about a templating engines will also be appreciated**

Regards

Comment: Any of the major frameworks will easily support MS SQL. The question would rather be, what do you need otherwise from that framework. Do you want a full MVC stack or rather just a micro framework that takes care of the request/response cycle. This question is hard to answer because nobody really knows more than one or two frameworks well enough to give an unbiased answer.

Comment: Templating engines: You don't need one, PHP itself is a templating engine. If you still insist, look at Twig or Smarty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's kill off the easy question first - by tempting, I'm assuming you mean **templating**. If so, Smarty is usually a very good contender as it is simple to learn and very powerful.

Now, for the framework. A wide variety of PHP frameworks have switched to PDO for SQL requests, which means that most of them will easily accomodate MS SQL. CodeIgniter does, so does CakePHP last time I checked.

Ultimately, pick what you know rather than picking something that looks fancy, unless you need the extra features. The learning curve will be smaller.

Comment: I already know PHP pretty well. I need read up PDO.So I guess it's plain PHP and PDO then :)

Comment: That's a pretty good solution, if you ask me. If you don't need all the fancy features that most of the frameworks around give you, why have them as overhead?